# Emails sent by Jenkins Email Extension plugin not received?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

```
pipeline 
{
  agent any
  stages
  {
    stage ('Start')
    {
      steps
      {
        echo 'Hello'
      }
    }
  }
  post
  {
    success
    {
      emailext (
          to: 'me@domain.zzz',
          subject: 'Test subject',
          body: 'Test body'
        )
    }
  }
}
```

This simple Jenkins pipeline seems to send email succesfully (output says: `Sending email to: me@domain.zzz`), but the emails are never received in the inbox.

There is nothing in the Jenkins log.
I can successfully send a test mail from `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> E-mail Notification`.
Here I am using [Email Extension plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/). Is there a way to send a test mail from Email Extension plugin? Is there any other way to find out why the emails are not sent/received?

Comment: In `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> E-mail Notification` in Advanced check `Enable Debug Mode` to have more logs in job logs

Comment: Thanks @Babasile, this saved me. I will describe the solution in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: under `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> E-mail Notification -> Advanced` check `Enable Debug Mode`. This gives a lot of info after the job is run!

The problem was that *TLS* was not enabled for Email Extension plugin since there is only an SSL checkbox available. When using classic `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> E-mail Notification` - there is a TLS checkbox, but not here.

[The solution](https://www.ais.com/how-to-enable-tlsv1-2-in-jenkins-for-smtp/) to enable startTLS on Debian Linux: log into Jenkins and edit `/etc/default/jenkins`. Edit the `JAVA_ARGS` and add the following: `"-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"`. Finally, this line for me looks like this:
`JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"`. Restart Jenkins: `sudo service jenkins restart`.

After this is done, emailing works.

Answer (score 0):

The E-mail Extension plugin (used here, as seen from `emailext` in the pipeline code attached to the question) has support for SMTP over TLS and the additional "TLS" configuration checkbox since v2.83 (see [release notes](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/releases/tag/email-ext-2.83)).